# Fibrations over BO

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

In Haynes Miller's "Notes on Cobordism" (pgs 39-40), he says the following:

Suppose we have a directed system of topological groups $G_0 \rightarrow G_1 \rightarrow \dots$ along with a compatible system of orthonormal representations $G_i \rightarrow O(i)$. Then if $G$ denotes the direct limit, applying the classifying space functor to the induced map $G \rightarrow O$ results in a fibration $BG \rightarrow BO$.

It seems to me like there is no reason this should be a fibration. For example, we could let all of our representations be trivial. Is there some condition on the representations that should be added?

Comment: Any map is a fibration up to homotopy : I think (but am not 100% sure) Miller is saying here that a fibration that replaces $BG\to BO$ is an interesting example.